# A regular polygon expressed as inequality

Tags: euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

A square can be described as

$$
\max(x - x_0, y - y_0) < r
$$

or

$$
|x - x_0| + |y - y_0| < r
$$

I am looking for a similar way to describe the set of all points inside a regular $n$-gon, so that $f(x,y) < r$ is true if and only if $(x, y)$ is inside the polygon. $r$ is expected to be the distance between the origin and one of the polygon vertices. I have a parameterization of one of the line segments:

The angle between two edges:
$$
\alpha = \frac{\pi}{2n}\left(n - 2\right) = \pi\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

Angle between ray through a vertex, and the line segment:
$$
\theta = \pi - \alpha = \pi\left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n}\right)\right) = \pi\left(1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right) =  \pi\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

The length of an edge:
$$
s = \sqrt{ 2r^2 -2r^2\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)} = \sqrt{2}r \sqrt{1 - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)}
$$

Point on the edge:
$$E(t) = (r, 0) + \frac{t}{s}\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\left(\theta\right) \\
\sin\left(\theta\right)
\end{bmatrix}, t\in[0, 1]
$$

Would the next step be to solve for $t$, such that the ray from $O$ to $P$ intersects $E(t)$. If $t$ is outside $[0, 1]$, rotate the coordinate system by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ and try the next edge. Take the distance as the shortest result.

Answer (score 1):

One way of encoding mathematically a regular polygon of "radius" $r$, centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, is as the set of points $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\begin{pmatrix}x_0+r\cos\frac{2\pi i}{n}\\y_0+r\sin\frac{2\pi i}{n}\end{pmatrix}$$ subject to the constraint of $\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2\le1$, ($a_i\in\mathbb{R}$).

More generally, any convex polygon with vertices $z_i=(x_i,y_i)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is the set of points $\frac{\sum_ia_i^2z_i}{\sum_ia_i^2}$, ($a_i\in\mathbb{R}$). This can be seen as the convex hull of the set of vertices.

Comment: What is $a_i$ here? Is it vertices, and $a_i^2$ the distance between $a_i$ and the origin.

Comment: @user877329 The $a_i$ are any $n$ real numbers subject to the constraint. They represent weighting factors for the vertices.

Comment: If $n$ is even, and all $a_i$ are equal, then this sum is (0, 0), due to symmetry. Is $a$ the reciprocal "radius"? I cannot see the anolog to the distance formula.

Comment: @user877329 $(0,0)$ is in the set even if $n$ is odd. This is as it should be since the set fills out the interior of the polygon. The $a_i$ are not fixed numbers, they are more like the $t$ in your formula, except there are $n$ of them.

Comment: @user877329 I've changed the answer to reflect that the polygon ought to have radius $r$ and center $(x_0,y_0)$.